# Unable To Download File In React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to download a file from the s3 bucket using the Presigned URL, but unfortunately, all the image formats like `jpeg/jpg/png` are not downloading instead they are opened to a new tab, following I have attached the solution I have tried with, none of them are working.

tried with npm package called [file-saver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-saver). This downloads everything except image files

```
import { saveAs } from 'file-saver';

const download = (url, filename) => {
   saveAs(url, filename)
}
```

tried with npm package called [js-file-download](https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-file-download). This is not working on other formats as well.

```
import downloadFile from 'js-file-download';

const download = (url, filename) => {
   downloadFile(url, filename)
}
```

tried with pure JS, but only the image files are not downloaded:

```
const download = (url, filename) => {
    const link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = url;
    link.setAttribute(
      'download',
      filename,
    );
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    link.parentNode.removeChild(link);
}
```

Comment: Why is this tagged with node.js, React, and Angular, but the code appears to only be about front-end JavaScript? Anyway, what browser are you trying this on? [Some older browsers don't support the `download` attribute](https://caniuse.com/download) (see also the Known Issues tab on that page, where it notes that some browsers only support same-origin links in the `download` attribute).

Comment: filename,  are you expecting to save to local computer from a browser? using filename, sorry that's not possible

Comment: @HereticMonkey I'm using an updated version of chrome and how can we achieve it if both things are not on the same origin?

Comment: @Keith `saveAs` function from `file-saver` expects two things. one is file URL or path and the second thing is filename

Comment: @Keith [The `download` attribute can take, as a value, a filename, which will be used as a suggested name for the file](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAnchorElement/download). It can't contain the *path*, only the filename.

Comment: file-saver is for node, not the browser..  You can't save directly to a filename from the browser,  well at least not without a file save dialog prompt..  And like mentioned  you can only hint a filename even then.

Comment: @HereticMonkey  Yes, I know.  But I'm not sure that's what the Op is expecting..  IOW, I think he's expecting to put something like `c:\test.exe` and it save..

Comment: @Zain The service providing the file would have to serve the file with the correct `Content-Disposition` header, which it is apparently not doing (see [the specification itself](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/links.html#downloading-resources) for more details on how everything works, or doesn't).

Answer (score -2):

You can either use an anchor element :

```html
import React from "react";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <a href="URL_PATH" download>
        Click to download
      </a>
    </div>
  );
}
```

or us the `file-saver` package as you did :

```html
import React from "react";
import { saveAs } from "file-saver";

export default function App() {
  const saveFile = () => {
    saveAs(
      "URL_PATH",
      "DOWNLOADED_FILE_NAME"
    );
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={saveFile}>download</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: please read the question and my solutions which I tried and didn;t works